# How to calculate sum of all visible div using their data also recalculated if div goes to hidden

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to do a cart system in js so that a user can click a div to add/remove to cart (toggle). I can toggle the cart list but can't sum the price in total. Any idea how to do that??

These are the product which can be added to cart

```
<div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-3 col-md-2">
<div id="feature-card" class="card" data-option-id="104" data-name="Activity Feed" data-price="200">
    <div class="card-content text-center">
        <i id="feature-icon" class="fa fa-feed"></i>
        <p>
            <?php _e( 'Activity Feed', 'techcare' ); ?>
        </p>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-3 col-md-2">
<div id="feature-card" class="card" data-option-id="103" data-name="Dashboard" data-price="200">
    <div class="card-content text-center">
        <i id="feature-icon" class="fa fa-dashboard"></i>
        <p>
            <?php _e( 'Dashboard', 'techcare' ); ?>
        </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

total calculation print div in the cart

```
<div class="col-md-9 col-sm-9 col-xs-9">
   <p id="left-margin-card-content" class="text-left"><strong><?php _e( 'Total', 'techcare' ); ?></strong></p>
</div>
```

I used this js to show/hide div to cart list

```
< script >
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('.card').one('click', function(event) {
        var id = $(this).attr('data-option-id'); //get specific div data id
        var name = $(this).attr('data-name'); //get specific div data name
        var price = $(this).attr('data-price'); //get specific div data price

        var NewItem = '<span id="' + id + '"><div class="col-md-9 col-sm-9 col-xs-9" ><p id="left-margin-card-content" class="text-left">' + name + '</p></div><div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-3" id="' + price + '"><p id="left-margin-card-content" class="text-right">$<span id="item-price">' + price + '</span></p></div><span>';

        var Item = $(NewItem).insertBefore('#features');


        $('.card[data-option-id = ' + id + ']').toggleClass("active-feature"); //click div toogle class



        $('.card[data-option-id = ' + id + ']').click(function(event) {
            $('.card[data-option-id = ' + id + ']').toggleClass("active-feature");

            $('#' + id).toggle();


        });

    });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've simplified the above example. On each of your cart items, add a class called `cart-item` (to the same element that contains `data-price`).

I'm looping through each of these elements and adding the `data-price` found.

```js
var total = 0;

$('.active-feature').each(function() {
    total += parseInt($(this).attr('data-price'));
});

console.log(total);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="active-feature" data-price="200"></div>
<div class="active-feature" data-price="100"></div>
<div class="active-feature" data-price="500"></div>
<div class="cart-item" data-price="10000" style="display: none;"></div> <!-- not active - don't add it! -->
```

Comment: It will sum all the product. I need to sum only that product which is in the cart only

Comment: How do you tell if an item is in the cart?

Comment: there is a style="display: inline;" in every div element of the cart ... if the product is deselect then style="display: none;" is set

Comment: @AshiqurRahman Okay, that's what my snippet is doing now. Checks for display: none; on the cart item. (the same element that has data-price)

Comment: Here's the [link](http://techcarebd.com/techcare.beta/pricing/web-app-1/)  can you visit ??

Comment: It's not whether they're hidden or not, you only want to add elements with the "active-feature" class. Give my new snippet a go

Comment: works perfectly .. but how to recalculate I added the js on click event. But When I deselect then price need to set to 0 or decrease. can u please check the [link](http://techcarebd.com/techcare.beta/pricing/web-app-1/) again?

Comment: @AshiqurRahman `$(<button selector here>).on('click', function() { // my code here })`. Please remember to mark the correct answer :)

Comment: Your idea of active-feature class is great. I never think of that

Comment: 1st click calculated value to 0. After second click calculation is okay. Why is this happening?  thanks for the help man.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the :visible selector to find only visible.

```
$(".someDiv:visible").each(....);
```

You can use the .not() selector to find only hidden.

```
$(".someDiv").not(":visible").each(....);
```

I think you can perform the same operation in your code with this one line.

Comment: The problem is the visible elements are arranged like <div><div> there are some other between every tag which causes failure to calculation total ... example : <div> <span><p> then again another <div>

Comment: $(document).find("selector") and $("selector") will match the same set of elements.